# send form data to server with api in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, api

my task is to make a form to send an Excel file and a message to the server, and I have a ***postman collection file*** that contains this array of objects:

```
"formdata": [
             {
                "key": "message",
                "value": "hello",
                "type": "text"
             },
              {
                "key": "users",
                "type": "file",
                "src": "path-to-.xlsx"
              }
            ]
```

and this is my simple form:

```
<div class="landing">
    <div class="intro-text">
      <div class="form-style-3">
        <form id="msgform" method="POST">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Message</legend>
            <label for="file">
              <span>File
                <span class="required">*</span>
              </span>
              <input type="file" name="file" id="input"
                accept="..csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel" />
            </label>
            <label for="message">
              <span>Message
                <span class="required">*</span>
              </span>
              <input name="message" id="message" type="text" />
            </label>
            <label>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </label>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this is my API connection function:

```
const url = 'path-to-api-url';
const form = document.getElementById('msgform');

form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(form);

  const formDataSerealized = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  console.log(formDataSerealized);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formDataSerealized),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    const json = await response.text();
    console.log(json);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

});
```

**My problem is**  when submitting I have in the console this error

```
{"errors":[{"message":"message not found"}]}
```

What Should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust your code to not use JSON formatting for the content.  That is the encoding that would be used if you posted the form without JS.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(form);

  const formDataSerealized = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  console.log(formDataSerealized);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formDataSerealized,
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    });
    const json = await response.text();
    console.log(json);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```

*EDIT* if you are sending a file in your form submission then use the content type `multipart/form-data` instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I made what you suggest but I have the same error with `422 (Unprocessable Entity) {"errors":[{"message":"message not found"}]}`.

Comment: what is the implementation on the server side.  what is expected? your formdata (from postman collection) is not formatted well.  it is formatted like a JS object. Postman has options for FormData in the request body

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data